# htaccess - Default error pages?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've been doing some looking around, but I can't seem to find anything, so I thought that this would be the best place for this question.

I have a website; and when I encounter an error on my website, (for example, a 404 error), I get an error page that looks like this:

[image: 404 Page]

This is of course an apache error.. However, if I go to a.rsg.sc, I get a default Chrome error:

[image: 404 Page]

As I mentioned, I've been looking high and low to find a way to change my errors to use default browser error pages. Keep in mind, **I don't want to use a custom error page, I want to use a default error page**.

Here's what's already in my .htaccess (If I remove it, I get the same result):

```
ErrorDocument 404 default
```

Thanks in advance for any information/solutions anyone can provide!

Comment: Can you share your `.htaccess` code

Comment: Sure thing! https://pastebin.com/enq4GBVv

Comment: Just bumping.. still an issue.

Comment: Bumping again... Still have no solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the page returned by the server has an HTTP status of 404 does not have any content (e.g. it returns a blank document), the browser will display one of its own error pages. If your server (in this case Apache), however, returns any content at all with the page, the browser will display that content.

If you want your 404 to be the browser's default, try:

```
ErrorDocument 404 ""
# or
Error Document /404.html # where 404.html is an empty file
```

On a side note, I would discourage using the browser's error pages as they are rarely seen for 404s. A client that sees the familiar Chrome error page might think that your server is down for instance without reading the full error description. Something with a title saying "404" or "Not found" tends to be a much more recognisable way to tell a client that your website works, but just this page isn't found. A custom error page would also allow you to point your visitors to similar links in your platform, which is something that Chrome currently does not do.